# Date Tables Marked as Date - Where is the Hierarchy?

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

When I mark a table as a Date table in my Tabular model, shouldn't a hierarchy automatically get built on the column I specify as the date column? Or do I still need to build that myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. the hierarchy will be built automatically. If not built automatically, check the hierarchy option to be selected in the image. Select the hierarchy option and you are good to go.

[image: Fields pane]